# android java need to use tenth place in equation

Tags: java, android

ok so im very new to android and java but im trying to build my first app and im stuck here is  part of my code so far

```
private void calculate() {
        year = Double.parseDouble(edityear.getText().toString());
        year = year / 12;
        year = year * 10;
        year = Math.round(year);
        year = year / 10;
```

now what i need to do it take the tenths place out and use it to pick what page im going to show.

so  if i started with 1985 i would end up with 165.4... so i want to take the 4 and use it in something like this

```
if (year == 4)  {
   setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. If you could give a better question, I could give a solution.

Comment: i need to use the tenth place to pick which page i want to show so if its 164.4 ill use the 4 or 133.8 ill use the 8...  i just dont know how to pull that number out

Answer (score 2):

```
calculate();
int whatYouNeed = (year * 10) % 10;
```

`%` is getting a rest of division result, so `14 % 10` will be 4